# One testcase not passing for Google Foobar Challenge Bringing-a-gun-to-a-guard-fight

Tags: python

The problem goes like this:

## Bringing a Gun to a Guard Fight

Uh-oh - you've been cornered by one of Commander Lambdas elite guards! Fortunately, you grabbed a beam weapon from an abandoned guard post while you were running through the station, so you have a chance to fight your way out. But the beam weapon is potentially dangerous to you as well as to the elite guard: its beams reflect off walls, meaning you'll have to be very careful where you shoot to avoid bouncing a shot toward yourself!

Luckily, the beams can only travel a certain maximum distance before becoming too weak to cause damage. You also know that if a beam hits a corner, it will bounce back in exactly the same direction. And of course, if the beam hits either you or the guard, it will stop immediately (albeit painfully).

Write a function solution(dimensions, your_position, guard_position, distance) that gives an array of 2 integers of the width and height of the room, an array of 2 integers of your x and y coordinates in the room, an array of 2 integers of the guard's x and y coordinates in the room, and returns an integer of the number of distinct directions that you can fire to hit the elite guard, given the maximum distance that the beam can travel.

The room has integer dimensions [1 < x_dim <= 1250, 1 < y_dim <= 1250]. You and the elite guard are both positioned on the integer lattice at different distinct positions (x, y) inside the room such that [0 < x < x_dim, 0 < y < y_dim]. Finally, the maximum distance that the beam can travel before becoming harmless will be given as an integer 1 < distance <= 10000.

For example, if you and the elite guard were positioned in a room with dimensions [3, 2], your_position [1, 1], guard_position [2, 1], and a maximum shot distance of 4, you could shoot in seven different directions to hit the elite guard (given as vector bearings from your location): [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, -2], [3, 2], [3, -2], [-3, 2], and [-3, -2]. As specific examples, the shot at bearing [1, 0] is the straight line horizontal shot of distance 1, the shot at bearing [-3, -2] bounces off the left wall and then the bottom wall before hitting the elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(13), and the shot at bearing [1, 2] bounces off just the top wall before hitting the elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(5).

## Languages

To provide a Java solution, edit Solution.java
To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py

## Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Java cases --
Input:
Solution.solution([3,2], [1,1], [2,1], 4)
Output:
    7

Input:
Solution.solution([300,275], [150,150], [185,100], 500)
Output:
    9

-- Python cases --
Input:
solution.solution([3,2], [1,1], [2,1], 4)
Output:
    7

Input:
solution.solution([300,275], [150,150], [185,100], 500)
Output:
    9

Use verify [file] to test your solution and see how it does. When you are finished editing your code, use submit [file] to submit your answer. If your solution passes the test cases, it will be removed from your home folder.

I have written the following code:

```
import math
def gcd(a, b):
    a, b = abs(a), abs(b)
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def mirrored_position(dimensions,guard_position,r,c):
    coord1 = dimensions[0]*(c)+((dimensions[0]-guard_position[0]) if c%2==1 else guard_position[0])
    coord2 = dimensions[1]*(r)+((dimensions[1]-guard_position[1]) if r%2==1 else guard_position[1])
    return (coord1,coord2)

def get_unit_vector(vect):
    if vect[0] == 0 and vect[1] == 0:
        return 0, 0
    elif vect[0] == 0:
        return 0, 1 if vect[1] > 0 else 0,-1
    elif vect[1] == 0:
        return 1,0 if vect[0] > 0 else -1, 0
    else:
        g = gcd(*vect)
        return (vect[0]/g, vect[1]/g)


def solution(dimensions, your_position, guard_position, distance):

    dist_to_guard=((your_position[0]-guard_position[0])**2+(your_position[1]-guard_position[1])**2)**0.5
    if distance<dist_to_guard:
        return 0
    if distance==dist_to_guard:
        return 1
    cols=distance/dimensions[0]+1
    rows=distance/dimensions[1]+1
    dirs=dict()


    for r in range(-rows,rows+1):
        for c in range(-cols,cols+1):
            guard_mirrored=mirrored_position(dimensions,guard_position,r,c)
            me_mirrored=mirrored_position(dimensions,your_position,r,c)
            dir_to_guard=get_unit_vector([guard_mirrored[0]-your_position[0],guard_mirrored[1]-your_position[1]])

            dist_to_guard=((your_position[0]-guard_mirrored[0])**2+(your_position[1]-guard_mirrored[1])**2)**0.5

            dist_to_me=((your_position[0]-me_mirrored[0])**2+(your_position[1]-me_mirrored[1])**2)**0.5
            dir_to_me=get_unit_vector([me_mirrored[0]-your_position[0],me_mirrored[1]-your_position[1]])

            if dist_to_me<=distance and dist_to_me>0:
                if dir_to_me in dirs.keys():
                    if dirs[dir_to_me][1]>=dist_to_me:
                        dirs[dir_to_me]=(False,dist_to_me)
                else:
                    dirs[dir_to_me]=(False,dist_to_me)
            if dist_to_guard<=distance and dist_to_guard>0:
                if dir_to_guard in dirs.keys():
                    if dirs[dir_to_guard][1]>dist_to_guard:
                        dirs[dir_to_guard]=(True,dist_to_guard)
                else:
                    dirs[dir_to_guard]=(True,dist_to_guard) 
    cnt=0
    for direction in dirs:
        if dirs[direction][0]==True:
            cnt+=1
    return cnt
```

But only one testcase is not passing. It is testcase number 3. I have been working on it since the past 4 days but got no where. I cannot understand what is the problem.

Comment: Hey man! I hope you have solved this. My solution is not getting tested for two cases. Those are cases 3 and 4.

Comment: I have not solved it yet. I am unable to see what the case getting left is.

Comment: What is your outpur for this test case ? `solution([2,5],[1,2],[1,4],11)`

Comment: My output for this test is 37.

Comment: I think the correct answer for that test case is 27

Comment: I had initialized my counter as 10 in place of zero while testing and so I got 37 as the answer. Now I am getting 27 only. This was quite unprofessional. My bad. Sorry

Comment: Test case 4 is for the case when the guard is at the passed distance and 1 has to be returned.